# Windows Update folder crashes Windows Explorer when I click it

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash, windows-update

I have a problem with my pc. Every time I go to control panel and click Windows Update, a window appears and says:

```
 Windows Explorer has stopped working, restarting Windows Explorer.
```

I don't know what is happening, and I need help with this problem.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit

Comment: create a crash dump and upload it: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have any windows explorer add-ons?  Such as Stardock customization's, etc?

Can you please try this?

**1.** Open CMD (click start, then type in CMD then hit enter)

**2.** paste the following line in:

```
%windir%\system32\wuapp.exe
```

**3.** Hit enter

Does windows explorer still crash?